# In libcurl, how to reset authorization headers when reusing a connection?

Tags: c, libcurl

Seems like this is not a new issue...
See "Curl: Reusing Authorization header" on https://curl.se/mail/lib-2007-02/0167.html.
And "Reused connection not reauthorising when auth details change" on https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1685.

But I still meet the same issue when I use CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER. Namely,
Libcurl will resend the token set in the first request even if in futher requests, new tokens are explicitly curl_easy_setopt with.

Everything works fine if I set CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE.
But if I do want to reuse the connection, is there a workaground? I am using version 7.68.0.

Answer (score 0):

The issue no longer exists in 7.79.0.